# Do we have any mechanism to send notification to all subscribers in one call?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-push-notification

Times of India CP has a query.
 
There is an API restriction of sending notifications to 1000 tokens in one call, this is mentioned in docs also.

Do we have any mechanism to send notification to all subscribers in one call?
Please provide the API to perform this functionality.

Please provide any reference.

We look forward to your help.

Comment: Did I understand correctly that it is documented that you can only do 1000 at the time... and you're asking if it is still possible to do more? Isn't that why the document is there...

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to [Topic-based Message Sending](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides-V5/android-topic-based-sending-0000001050040114-V5?ha_source=hms1)

[image]

Hope this could help with your issue. :)